# Problem with SDL_Mixer/MikMod playing XM files properly

Tags: sdl, music

Some of the music I've made for my game have note bends in them (1xx Portamento up)...The problem is that when they play in my game, the note bends and then goes right back to original note instead of staying at the new tone it bends into.

I believe this to be an issue with SDL_Mixer and not with the XM file itself since it plays just fine in any tracker program I load it into.  Is there anything in the SDL_Mixer loading/playing functions that I could do to fix this?

Comment: To confirm it's not the XM file, have you played it with FMOD and/or BassMOD? Be sure to play it in as many players as you can. tracker formats aren't a perfect standard. Could you also provide an example file? We don't need your song, just a sequence with notebending. Bonus points for audio renders of intended effect and what you get in the game.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the module formats (family which XM format is part of) are not perfectly specified, and various replay routines play them slightly differently.

There's really nothing you can do, apart from "fixing" the replay routine (to which you probably have no source) or modifying the XM itself (so it plays "wrong" in the XM editor, but "right" with your replay routine of choise).

Answer (score 1):

MikMod is, for lack of better words, often horrible. It is likely the root cause for your misrendering. The mixing in SDL_mixer doesn't know anything about notes or effects, it just mixes together one or more streams of audio.

I asked some friends of mine with extensive experience in module quirks and they recommend using a more sane module rendering library, like [DUMB](http://dumb.sourceforge.net/) (no affiliation), which I've used in the past in my software.